# PhotoScroller Example iOS MaxZoom?

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, ipad, ios4

i am using the Photoscroller Example from:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

but i don´t see how i can set the maximum zoom!?

regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a method called

`- (void)`setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds

there he set the maxzoomscale